# How to properly start x11vnc through systemd socket activation?

Tags: vnc, systemd

I would like to setup system socket activation for x11vnc on a server but I'm not getting the proper configuration to achieve my requirements.

I would like to:

- Open a new VNC connection to the server on standard port (5900). Socket activation should launch x11vnc on the currently running X server.
- Be able to connect a second client to the same vnc server so they can both see the same screen.
- When the last client disconnects, `x11vnc` should be stoped.
- A new client connection re-launches `x11vnc` if it is not running.

Systemd is at 225 and x11vnc at 0.9.13.

It seems I can't use a simple `x11vnc.socket`+`x11vnc.service` files combination because `x11vnc` will map to the next TCP port (5901) if it detects the standard port (5900) is already used (by the systemd socket).

So I use a systemd "proxy" (see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-socket-proxyd.html) so that systemd listen to 5900 and x11vnc on 5901. So I have:

**proxy-to-x11vnc.socket**:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=5900
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**proxy-to-x11vnc.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc
Requires=x11vnc.service
After=x11vnc.service
[Service]
User=myuser
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd 127.0.0.1:5901
```

**x11vnc.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc
[Service]
User=myuser
StandardError=syslog
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /home/myuser/.Xauthority -shared -display :0 -rfbport 5901 -noipv6
```

Only **proxy-to-x11vnc.socket** is started/enabled.

The problem with this setup is:

- On first client connection, I see x11vnc being started and listening on the proper port, but the client connection just "hangs". Looking at the server logs `x11vnc` does not receive the connection attempt.
- Killing the client and reconnecting successfully show the remote display.
- Disconnecting the client will let `x11vnc` terminate, but I then cannot re-connect to it. `x11vnc.service` is in the *inactive (dead)* state.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's some nice explanation of the proxy: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/03/docker-systemd-socket-activation/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no a complete solution for your problem. Your third point is not possible with the current systemd-socket-proxyd, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2106) on GitHub to address this issue.

For your first point, the problem is that x11vnc take quite a long time to start and does not accept connection until it is completely started. The solution, as proposed by atlassian [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/03/docker-systemd-socket-activation/) is to add a sleep after starting the vnc server. The systemd-socket-proxyd will then wait before forwarding the communications.

For the second point, there is the `-share` option for x11vnc to allow it to accept more than one connection.

The third point is unfortunatly not doable. But you can stop the vnc server by hand with `systemctl stop x11vnc`.

Even if you can not stop x11vnc automatically, the forth point will work when the server is stopped manually.

To summarize, here is the files you need:

#### /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc-proxy.socket

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=5900

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc-proxy.service

```
[Unit]
Requires=x11vnc.service
After=x11vnc.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd 127.0.0.1:15900
```

#### /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -shared -rfbport 15900
ExecStartPost=/usr/local/bin/waitport 127.0.0.1 15900

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Please note the `-forever` option to keep the vnc server running when all clients are disconnected. It's the only way I found to be able to reconnect until the [feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2106) is done. The `ExecStartPost` is the part that wait until the vnc server is up and running before letting the proxy to forward the connection.

#### /usr/local/bin/waitport

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1
port=$2
tries=15

for i in `seq $tries`; do
    if /usr/bin/nc $host $port > /dev/null ; then
        # Ready
        exit 0
    fi

    /bin/sleep 1
done

# FAIL
exit -1
```

With all this scripts setup, you can then enable the x11vnc-proxy.socket with `systemctl enable x11vnc-proxy.socket` and start it `systemctl start x11vnc-proxy.socket`.

Comment: Just to note, you can simplify your answer a bit, as x11vnc also supports the `-inetd` option flag. Combined with a `StandardInput=socket` directive in `x11vnc.service`, it makes `x11vnc-proxy.service` redundant. Read about the `StandardInput=socket` option in the man page for `systemd.exec`, and note that it our case we are specifying a single socket only and **do not** have `Accept=yes` set. Doing this will also make the `waitport` process unnecessary.